# Pinch to Zoom in Android with Photoswipe, Hammer.js and Transit.js

Tags: android, cordova, pinchzoom, photoswipe, hammer.js

I've used hammer and transit, but still can get it work correctly.

In detail: it zooms, but zooms ALL the images, not only the visible one, and moreover it's not draggable.

I tried with several plugins (like pep.js) but, since I cannot reach the image directly, I cannot apply them to it. (the ui-overlay masks them).
Here's my code.
Where do I wrong?
I used PhoneGap and JqueryMobile

Here is the code:

```
var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage;
var options = {
  enableMouseWheel        : false , 
  enableKeyboard          : false, 
  captionAndToolbarOpacity: 1,
  backButtonHideEnabled   : false,   //do not modify - causes android crash
  allowUserZoom           : true,
  getImageMetaData        : function(el){
                        return{
                            id  : el.getAttribute('id')
                        }
                    }
  },
  photoSwipeInstance = $('#lstImages a',e.target).photoSwipe(options,currentPage.attr('id'));
  photoSwipeInstance.addEventHandler(window.Code.PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onDisplayImage,function(e){

      //OVERRIDES THE PHISICAL ANDROID BACK BUTTON BEHAVIOUR AND STAY IN PAGE
       document.addEventListener('backbutton',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
             window.Code.PhotoSwipe.activeInstances[0].instance.hide(); 
             window.location.hash = $.mobile.urlHistory.getActive();
    },false)

    var currentImage = photoSwipeInstance.getCurrentImage();
    var id = currentImage.metaData.id;
    var $img = $('.ps-carousel-item-'+id+' img');
    var $wrap = $('.ps-carousel-'+id);

    $('.ps-uilayer').hammer({prevent_default:true}).on('pinchin pinchout',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.gesture.stopPropagation();
        e.gesture.stopDetect();

        switch(e.type){
           case 'pinchout':
           $img.transition({scale: 2});
        break;
           case 'pinchin':
           $img.transition({scale: 1});
        break;
            }       
    })
    $('.ps-document-overlay').pep(); //THIS IS THE ATTEMPT TO MAKE IMG DRAGGABLE
});
```

Any suggestion about why it doesn't work proprerly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

in css file for the ui-overlay?

Comment: I can't use it because it is used by the photozoom plugin to do all the things like swapping and so on...
Anyway this issue is no more pending, because I took another way to do this. Thank you the same!

Comment: can you post hare your solution. i am face same issue